# android post data on web

Tags: java, php, android, http

I am trying to send data from android to web through HTTP post . But I don't know how to receive data from android to web.

Here is my activity code:

```
    public class Chatit extends Activity {
    Context context = this;
    ChatDbHelper chatDbHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
    EditText editText;
    ListView listView;
    Cursor cursor;
    ListDataAdapter listDataAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chatit);

        editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listDataAdapter = new ListDataAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.row_layout);
        listView.setAdapter(listDataAdapter);


        chatDbHelper = new ChatDbHelper(context);
        sqLiteDatabase = chatDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = chatDbHelper.getChat(sqLiteDatabase);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String name;

                name = cursor.getString(0);

                DataProvider dataProvider = new DataProvider(name);
                listDataAdapter.add(dataProvider);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }

  /*  public void send(View view){
        String chat = editText.getText().toString();

        chatDbHelper = new ChatDbHelper(context);
        sqLiteDatabase = chatDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        chatDbHelper.addChat(chat,sqLiteDatabase);

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Message sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        chatDbHelper.close();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,Chatit.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } */



    public void send(View view) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(editText.getText().toString().length()<1){

            // out of range
            Toast.makeText(this, "please enter something", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            String chat = editText.getText().toString();

            chatDbHelper = new ChatDbHelper(context);
            sqLiteDatabase = chatDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            chatDbHelper.addChat(chat,sqLiteDatabase);

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Message sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            chatDbHelper.close();
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,Chatit.class);
            startActivity(intent);

           // pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            new MyAsyncTask().execute(editText.getText().toString());
        }


    }

    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double> {

        @Override
        protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            postData(params[0]);
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Double result){
          //  pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "command sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
       // protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){
        //    pb.setProgress(progress[0]);
       // }

        public void postData(String valueIWantToSend) {
            // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://somewebsite.com/receiver.php");

            try {
                // Add your data
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("myHttpData", valueIWantToSend));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            }
        }}}
```

Please tell me:

Am i doing right or not ?

How can i receive data from android to web?

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to first start by noting a few things I see in your code.

1. You are using HttpClient with NameValuePairs for your post, which would have been fine in a little while ago, but are now deprecated. I'd advise you to look in to Okhttp and Retrofit, as they will make your life A LOT easier in terms of network calls and separate your code in to layers so that unit testing is easier.

You can find Okhttp here: https://github.com/square/okhttp

2. In your doInBackground function, you are making the network call, but then are returning null. Try changing the return type of the AsyncTask to something like a custom object that holds reference to what you expect your response to look like, or if you follow the Observable pattern in android, you can make this A LOT cleaner. However, it's a bit of a learning curve. For your reference, here is a video on RxJava that you may find useful moving forward.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k3D0cWyNno4

3. Going back to why I'd advise you to stay away from AsyncTask's is due to the following dilemma:

AsyncTasks are hard to control because they are bound to the context in which they are started. So if you execute this task here, you must manage the state of your app in all of the the life cycle callbacks in order to ensure any state of change to your Activity doesn't negatively impact the UI. Further, the AsyncTask is a fire and forget, unless you do an task.get(), which will wait for the task to return the intended object. However, make no mistake about how this affects your app. If you, for example, change the orientation of your screen you will lose the background thread and also any data you may have intermittently received will be lost. AND, this AsyncTask will not execute again unless you explicitly fire off another thread. Sounds like a lot of work just to make sure your networking is done properly, huh?

One workaround developers have made to this is to make that AsyncTasks bound to Fragments instead of Activities, so that you can use the setRetainInstance method of the Fragment to keep track of the state of the screen. Still, as you grow in to more complex app states and want to manage things within their own "realm" so to speak, you will want to separate logic that pertains to networking in it's own layer so that 1) it can be tested properly, 2) makes your code cleaner, and 3) allows you to not have to worry about managing so many states.

Finally, if you still choose to take the approach you have taken, which is fine btw, just make sure you replace the deprecated HTTP client and return something from your AsyncTask background method so that you can retrieve it onPostExecute.

```
    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Object> {

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // I'd advise you to make the return type an Object, as whatever
        // the server returns will be easier to manage that way.
        // I placed a generic object here for now, create a custom one.
        Object response = postData(params[0]);
        return response;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Double result){

      //  pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "command sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    public void postData(String valueIWantToSend) {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        public static final MediaType JSON
            = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        try {
            RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, valueIWantToSend);
              Request request = new Request.Builder()
                  .url("http://somewebsite.com/receiver.php")
                  .post(body)
                  .build();
              Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
              return response.body().string();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // do something
        }
    }}}
```

I'll leave incorporating retrofit and jackson as an exercise for you if you'd like to do that. Hopefully this shed some light on how to solve your problem and some insight in how to make it better. I tried my best to explain based on whatever experience I have had with this stuff, hope it helps!